# How to update PostgreSQL timezone database

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I use PostgreSQL version 9.5 on server. Timezone database apparently becomes outdated as time passes.

For example, according to [icann mailing list](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2018-October/000051.html), Volgograd, Russia moved from +3 to +4. However, in my database it looks like it is still in the same time zone as Moscow, Russia:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Moscow';
        timezone        
------------------------
 2001-02-16 20:38:40+03


SELECT TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Volgograd';
        timezone        
------------------------
 2001-02-16 20:38:40+03
```

Is there a way to update just timezone database without updating or reinstalling the entire PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

you can set a timezone to your database for example:

```
alter DATABASE your_dabase  set timezone  = '+N' --number of timezone
```

or can use alter system to change to all databases in server:

```
alter system set timezone to '+N'; --number of timezone, reload configuration
```

Regards

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sets the _default timezone for the database_. I am satisfied with all my databases' time zones, the problem is different. Time zones offsets change over time. The data about those offsets is hard-coded by default (as far as I know) and can be updated only during update of the entire PostgreSQL application.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CA%2B%3DV_fNpDShFXmPzhBjmMwn4EMvgyirMvJsq%2BrdQCN3VC3ac3g%40mail.gmail.com) on the mailing list, if PostgreSQL was compiled with `--with-system-tzdata` then it's just a matter of updating your system tzdata files (typically using your distro's package manager). You can check if it was compiled with that option by running `pg_config --configure`, but it has to be the specific `pg_config` binary that was built alongside the server.

If it wasn't compiled with that option then Postgres uses a packaged (and likely outdated) copy of tzdata which appears to live in `share/timezone/` (within the installation dir), and can apparently be manually updated with help from the `zic` utility.

In either case, it's claimed that existing sessions can't read the new data but new sessions will be able to. Maybe worth restarting the server anyway as a precaution.

Answer (score -1):

The `pg_timezone_names` view is populated when the server starts, it recursively reads the timezone files from `<your Postgres dir>/src/timezone` and they are used to provide date for the view.

1. If you can replace the timezone file `<your Postgres dir>    /src/timezone/data/tzdata.zi` with the latest updates on timezones
   then this might resolve the issue.
2. If you can update the View `pg_timezone_names`

If we are using the Cloud Version there is no way we can replace or update these files as everything is managed by the Infastrcture

[image]